# Tridion Object cache is not working in content service in Tridion sites 9.6

Tags: content-delivery, object-cache, 9.6

We are using Tridion sites 9.6 along with DXA 2.2 Java. The cd services are installed on Linux env and we are facing an issue where content broker queries are not being cached.

ObjectCache is enabled in cd_storage file and also in ItemTypes is cached as true

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Configuration xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" Version="11.6" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="schemas/cd_storage_conf.xsd">
    <!--Optional:-->
    <!--
        Default Namespace Configuration
        The parameter to determine the default namespace
        'tcm' - Tridion Sites
    -->
    <Namespace default="${namespaceprefix:-tcm}"/>
    <Global>
        <!--Optional:-->
        <ObjectCache Enabled="true">
            <!--Optional:-->
            <Policy Class="com.tridion.cache.LRUPolicy" Type="LRU">
                <Param Name="MemSize" Value="16mb"/>
            </Policy>
            <Features>
                <Feature Class="com.tridion.cache.DependencyTracker" Type="DependencyTracker"/>
            </Features>
            <RemoteSynchronization FlushCacheDuringDisconnectInterval="${objectcacheflushinterval:-20000}" Queuesize="${objectcachequeuesize:-20000}" ServiceMonitorInterval="${objectcachemonitorinterval:-10000}">
                <Connector Class="com.tridion.cache.JMSCacheChannelConnector" Topic="${activemqtopic:-Tridion}">
                    <JndiContext>
                        <Property Name="java.naming.factory.initial" Value="org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory"/>
                        <Property Name="java.naming.provider.url" Value="${activemqurl:-tcp://localhost:61616?soTimeout=50000&amp;wireFormat.maxInactivityDuration=0}"/>
                        <Property Name="topic.${activemqtopic:-Tridion}" Value="${activemqtopicdest:-TridionCCS}"/>
                        <Property Name="userName" Value="${activemqclientuser:-admin}"/>
                        <Property Name="password" Value="${activemqclientsecret:-admin}"/>
                    </JndiContext>
                </Connector>
            </RemoteSynchronization>
        </ObjectCache>
        <Storages>
            <StorageBindings/>
            <Wrappers/>
            <Storage Class="com.tridion.storage.persistence.JPADAOFactory" Id="defaultdb" Type="persistence" dialect="ORACLESQL">
                <Pool AcquireRetryAttempts="${dbretryattempts:-1}" CheckoutTimeout="120" IdleTimeout="120" MonitorInterval="60" Size="100" Type="jdbc"/>
                <DataSource Class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
                    <Property Name="driverType" Value="thin"/>
                    <Property Name="networkProtocol" Value="tcp"/>
                    <Property Name="URL" Value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS_LIST =(ADDRESS =(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=xxx.xxx.xx.xx)(PORT=1831)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=SDLPCDB)))"/>
                    <Property Name="user" Value="Tridion_BROKER"/>
                    <Property Name="password" Value="encrypted:T2YHFgxbuWBh+5dA4e9NKA=="/>
                </DataSource>
            </Storage>
        </Storages>
    </Global>
    <ItemTypes cached="true" defaultStorageId="defaultdb">            
    </ItemTypes>
    <ConfigRepository CacheEnabled="${configcacheenabled:-true}" CacheExpirationDuration="1800" ClientId="registration" ClientSecret="${registrationpassword:-encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY=}" ConnectionTimeout="10000" ServiceMonitorPollDuration="${servicemonitorpollduration:-120}" ServiceUri="${discoveryurl:-http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc}" TokenServiceUrl="${tokenurl:-http://localhost:8082/token.svc}">
        <!-- ClientSecret="Reg1str@t10nP@ssw0rd" -->
        <Roles>
            <Role Name="ContentServiceCapability" Url="${contenturl:-http://localhost:8081/content.svc}"/>
        </Roles>
    </ConfigRepository>
    <OData>
        <DefaultTop>25</DefaultTop>
        <FixedPublicationId>1</FixedPublicationId>
    </OData>
</Configuration>
```

Comment: Are you using ActiveMQ ? can you share more information on  how the caching is setup and what caching is used , so we can respond accoridngly

Comment: Abdul , are you still facing the issue , if so can you share more information